# Simplest jQuery plugin, why doesn't this work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I must be missing something very basic & think I need a cardboard partner.
I've added a new method to jQuery, yet, as in the firebug command-line experience below, it just doesn't work because the method doesn't exist.

The jQuery tutorials all say to write exactly this code, what is wrong with it?

> $.fn.bob = function() {alert('bob!');}

>function()

> $.bob()

>TypeError: $.bob is not a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.fn` refers to the jQuery function `$()`:

So your function would have to be called like this:

```
$('anything').bob();
```

You can also extend the jQuery object directly, and call the function as you intended:

```
$.bob = function(){ alert('bob!') }
$.bob();
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I should have realized it, but I now cling to a faint hope that my moment of failure will some day help someone else ;-)

Comment: No problem. I'm sure you're not the first one asking this question!

Answer (score 1):

you need to use it on a jquery object:

`$('body').bob()`

Comment: Right, of course. I was confused because I wanted to replace my calls to $.ajax with $.myAjax - like a static call. Looks like I needed $.myAjax = function() {}

Comment: as Frederik said above, just define the function on `$.myAjax()` instead of `$.fn`